# How to turn result of "SELECT *" INTO array in stored procedure MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get some record and store it into a log_record before the record are being delete.

Here are my tables. But the problem is I don't know how to turn the result of `SELECT *` into an array, so I can't loop it inside the stored procedure for inserting it into record based on column name and column value.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account 
(
    id_account int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    account_location tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    create_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_account)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO account (account_name, account_location) 
VALUES ('Me', 110),
       ('You', 110),
       ('Them', 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_record 
(
    id_log INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    type tinyint not null,
    table_affected VARCHAR(10),
    column_name VARCHAR(30),
    new_value VARCHAR(255),
    create_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint C_TYPE_LOG check(type IN (0,1))
)ENGINE=INNODB;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS deleteProcedure;

CREATE PROCEDURE deleteProcedure
    (IN KeyValue INT, 
     IN TableName VARCHAR(30), 
     IN PrimaryKey VARCHAR(30), 
     OUT messageResult VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE ColumnName VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE ColumnValue VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE result TINYINT(1);
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;

        SET messageResult = null;
    END;

    -- # THIS FOR TURN INTO ARRAY AREA
    -- # But i don't know how to turn result of "SELECT *" INTO array of value and array of column name
    SET @ArrayColumnValue = '';
    SET @ArrayColumnName = '';
        
    SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE PrimaryKey = KeyValue;
        
    START TRANSACTION;
        -- # LOOP AREA FOR INSERT 
        WHILE (LOCATE(',', @ArrayColumnValue) > 0)
        DO
            SET @ColumnName = ELT(1, @ArrayColumnName);
            SET @ArrayColumnName= SUBSTRING(@ArrayColumnName, LOCATE(',',@ArrayColumnName) + 1);
            SET @ColumnValue = ELT(1, @ArrayColumnValue);
            SET @ArrayColumnValue= SUBSTRING(@ArrayColumnValue, LOCATE(',',@ArrayColumnValue) + 1);

            INSERT INTO log_record(type, table_affected, column_name, old_value) 
            VALUES('DELETE', TableName, @ColumnName ,@ColumnValue);
        END WHILE;
            
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO result;

        -- # CHECK IS SUCCESS BEING INSERT
        IF (@result = 0) THEN
            ROLLBACK;

        SET messageResult = 'FAILED';
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM TableName WHERE PrimaryKey = KeyValue;
        SET messageResult = 'SUCCESS';
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END
```

Or do  do it wrong from beginning? Like using the wrong method to get about silly thing than should be done easily.

I'm new one to this thing, please if you know that I'm using wrong way, you can tell me using other way. TT

Comment: You can't use variables for table and column names. You need to construct the query dynamically and use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to execute it.

Comment: And to get the column names, you can use a query from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: @Barmar i have updated it and there is no error in the SP

Comment: There should be. `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE PrimaryKey = KeyValue;` should complain that there's no table named `TableName`

Comment: @Barmar my mistake when paste it sorry, as for turn a result of SELECT * INTO an array is there a way?

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays.

Comment: TableName is insert it as param when we call deleteProcedure

Comment: You need to use `SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', col1, col2, col3, ...) INTO @ArrayColumnValue ...`

Comment: I know it's a parameter, but you can't use a parameter as the table name in a query. It looks for a table actually named `TableName`, it doesn't expand the variable.

Comment: You need to create the query by concatenating the variables into the SQL, then using `PREPARE`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Got it i'll try to read it first i hope find an answer on that, Thanks. :)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks it's took me a week to make this happen (i'm idiot TT), your suggention is very help me to complate the SP like what i want. But i'm not sure if this bunch line of code are save from SQL injection, or perhaps do i need to use prepare stetment in application layer to call this SP? And also is there a way to pass long string into params? I'm set it VARCHAR(1000) on 3rd params, i don't know if it works if the character is set more than 255 length? because if i'm correct VARCHAR only store 255 length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm test it on maria DB, and work prefectly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteProcedure(IN LogTableName VARCHAR(100), IN TableName VARCHAR(100), in InputValues varchar(1000))
ProcLabel:BEGIN
    -- Local Variable
    DECLARE log_column_names, column_names, current_column_name, current_input_value, column_names_repeat, input_values_found, input_value_params VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE table_key_name, this_table_name, table_key_data_type VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE column_start_pos, column_comma_pos, column_loop_count, row_start_pos, row_comma_pos, row_loop_count, total_column_loop_count, input_values_found_length SMALLINT;
    DECLARE column_end_loop, row_end_loop, table_key_data_type_char TINYINT;
    -- Declare Condition
    DECLARE TableNotFound CONDITION for 1146 ;
    
    -- Exit Handler
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR TableNotFound
    BEGIN
        SELECT CONCAT('Table ', @this_table_name ,' Are Not Found') MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;
    
    -- Set Array Column
    SET @this_table_name = TableName;
    SET @SQL = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ? INTO @column_names";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @this_table_name;
    
    SET @this_table_name = LogTableName;
    SET @SQL = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ? AND column_key != 'PRI' AND column_name != 'create_at' INTO @log_column_names";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @this_table_name;
    
    SET @SQL = "SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ? AND column_key = 'PRI' INTO @table_key_name, @table_key_data_type";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt USING TableName;
    
    SELECT IF(LOWER(SUBSTRING(@table_key_data_type, -3, 3) != 'int'), TRUE, FALSE) INTO @table_key_data_type_char;
   
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("INSERT INTO ", LogTableName ," (", @log_column_names ,") VALUES");
    
    -- Set Default Value Before Loop
    SET @SQLVAL = '';
    SET @row_start_pos = 1;
    SET @row_comma_pos = LOCATE(',', InputValues);
    SET @row_loop_count = 0;
    SET @total_column_loop_count = 0;
    SET @input_values_found = '';
    SET @input_value_params = InputValues;
    
    InputValueRepeat:REPEAT
        IF @row_comma_pos > 0 THEN
            SET @current_input_value = SUBSTRING(InputValues, @row_start_pos, @row_comma_pos - @row_start_pos);
            SET @row_end_loop = 0;
        ELSE
            SET @current_input_value = SUBSTRING(InputValues, @row_start_pos);
            SET @row_end_loop = 1;
        END IF;
        
        SET @SQLC = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ", TableName ," WHERE ", @table_key_name ," = ", @current_input_value ," INTO @record_found");
        PREPARE stmtC FROM @SQLC;
        EXECUTE stmtC;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtC;
        
        IF @record_found = 1 AND @row_loop_count > 0 AND @column_loop_count IS NOT NULL THEN
            set @SQLVAL = CONCAT(@SQLVAL,",");
        END IF;
        
        IF @record_found = 1 THEN
            SET @column_start_pos = 1;
            SET @column_comma_pos = LOCATE(',', @column_names);
            SET @column_names_repeat = @column_names;
            SET @column_loop_count = 0;
            
            ColumnNameRepeat:REPEAT
                IF @column_comma_pos > 0 THEN
                    SET @current_column_name = SUBSTRING(@column_names_repeat, @column_start_pos, @column_comma_pos - @column_start_pos);
                    SET @column_end_loop = 0;
                ELSE
                    SET @current_column_name = SUBSTRING(@column_names_repeat, @column_start_pos);
                    SET @column_end_loop = 1;
                END IF;
    
                SET @SQLSV = CONCAT("SELECT ", @current_column_name ," FROM ", TableName ," WHERE ", @table_key_name ," = ? INTO @current_column_value");
                PREPARE stmtSV FROM @SQLSV;
                EXECUTE stmtSV USING @current_input_value;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtSV;
            
                SET @SQLVAL = CONCAT(@SQLVAL, "('", CONCAT_WS("','", 'D', TableName, @current_column_name, @current_column_value, @current_input_value) ,"')");

                IF @column_end_loop = 0 THEN
                    SET @column_names_repeat = substring(@column_names_repeat, @column_comma_pos + 1);
                    SET @column_comma_pos = LOCATE(',', @column_names_repeat);
                    set @SQLVAL = CONCAT(@SQLVAL,",");
                END IF;
            
                SET @column_loop_count = @column_loop_count + 1;
            
                UNTIL @column_end_loop = 1

            END REPEAT;
            SET @total_column_loop_count = @total_column_loop_count + @column_loop_count;
            IF @input_values_found != '' THEN
                IF (@table_key_data_type_char = TRUE) THEN
                    SET @input_values_found = CONCAT_WS("','", @input_values_found, @current_input_value);
                ELSE 
                    SET @input_values_found = CONCAT_WS(",", @input_values_found, @current_input_value);
                END IF;
            ELSE 
                SET @input_values_found = @current_input_value;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        
        IF @row_end_loop = 0 THEN
            SET InputValues = substring(InputValues, @row_comma_pos + 1);
            SET @row_comma_pos = LOCATE(',', InputValues);
        ELSE 
            set @SQLVAL = CONCAT(@SQLVAL,";");
        END IF;
        
        SET @row_loop_count = @row_loop_count + 1;
                       
        UNTIL @row_end_loop = 1

    END REPEAT;
    
    IF (table_key_data_type_char = TRUE) THEN
        SET @input_values_found = CONCAT("'", @input_values_found ,"'");   
    END IF;
    
    SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(@input_values_found)) INTO @input_values_found_length;
    if @input_values_found_length < 3 AND @table_key_data_type_char = TRUE OR @table_key_data_type_char = FALSE AND @input_values_found_length < 1 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT("Can't find input value : [", @input_value_params ,"] on table ", TableName) MESSAGE_TEXT; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        LEAVE ProcLabel;
    END IF;
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    
    SET @SQL = CONCAT(@SQL, @SQLVAL);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() into @affected_row;
    
    IF (@affected_row != @total_column_loop_count) THEN
        SELECT CONCAT("Failed to insert data expected row : ", @column_loop_count ,", affected row : ", @affected_row) MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        LEAVE ProcLabel;
    END IF;
    
    SET @affected_row = 0;
    
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("DELETE FROM ", TableName ," WHERE ", @table_key_name ," IN (", @input_values_found ,")");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @affected_row;
    
    IF (@affected_row = 0) THEN
        SELECT CONCAT("Failed to delete ", TableName ," on record key ", @input_values_found) MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        LEAVE ProcLabel;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT CONCAT("Success ", @affected_row ," record on ", TableName ," was deleted") MESSAGE_TEXT;
    COMMIT;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

We need to call this SP like `Call DeleteProcedure('[to table]','[from table]','[array of keys to delete]');` => `Call DeleteProcedure('log_history','orders','1,3,4');`

So we can choose as much as you want use it with comma sparator like '1,2,3' on the 3rd parameter. But i'm haven't try it on more then hundred of keys, because 3rd params data type is varchar(1000).
I hope there is someone can solve this issue in the near future.